# Using Assuming with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I have the following code that includes Assuming to cut through irrelevant detail, or so I had hoped.

```
Assuming[w > 1/2 && P < 1, Reduce[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) > 0]]
```

To my detriment Mathematica generates an output whose first condition is $w<\frac{1}{2}$

How can I get Mathematica to use my assumptions to focus on only those values that apply within those assumptions?

Comment: `Assuming[w > 1/2 && P < 1, 
 FullSimplify@Reduce[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) > 0]]`?

Comment: Oh dear. That was beautiful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Assuming >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html):

- Assuming *affects the default assumptions for all functions that have an* Assumptions *option*.

`Assumptions` is not an option for `Reduce`:

```
Options[Reduce]
```

> {Backsubstitution -> False, Cubics -> False, GeneratedParameters -> C,
>           Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> False, 
>       WorkingPrecision -> ∞}

You can wrap `Reduce` with `FullSimplify`:

```
Assuming[w > 1/2 && P < 1, FullSimplify@Reduce[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) > 0]]
```

> f (-1 + P + 2 w - 2 P w) < P

Answer (score 10):

There is a warning in the docs for [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html):

> Some of the transformations used by `FullSimplify` are only generically correct.

It's also true for `Simplify` (e.g. `Simplify[Sin[Pi x]/x == 0, x ∈ Integers]`).  Often one uses `Reduce` to avoid such errors.

One way to introduce assumptions in `Reduce` is to include them as constraints:

```
Assuming[w > 1/2 && P < 1, 
 Reduce[$Assumptions && P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) > 0]]
(*  w > 1/2 && P < 1 && f < -(P/(1 - P - 2 w + 2 P w))  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @kglr (+1) [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) will ignore the conditions in [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) but [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) will use them.

```
Composition[
  MemberQ[Assumptions],
  Keys,
  Options
  ] /@ {Reduce, FullSimplify}
(* {False, True} *)
```

Another option would have been to incorporate your assumptions into the expression to `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[
 And @@ {
   P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) > 0,
   w > 1/2,
   P < 1
   }
 ]
(* w > 1/2 && P < 1 && f < -(P/(1 - P - 2 w + 2 P w)) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect method is written as follows.

`Reduce[expr && $Assumptions, vars] // Simplify`

(e.g. Reduce for $e^a>1$, whose result is $a>0$)
[image: Step by step demonstration]

This way is much better than the `Reduce[...]//Simplify` way, which also exerts the global `$Assumptions`, **but costs much more efforts and may bring about failure**. That's because in `Reduce` part it tries to find all the possible solutions in the whole domain of vars, which is totally not necessary if you assign (e.g.)`a>=0`. Even worse is it's too heavy-loaded for Mathematica to give a result, and then it gives up. But my way of using `$Assumptions` in `*expr*` part of `Reduce` tells it not to search in the other region.

The `Trace` functions shows this:
[image]

A very simple example in which `Reduce` fails but `reduce` succeeds:
[image]