# Combinations of variables that satisfy my inequality

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

This question is a continuation to one answered by kglr [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179820/using-assuming-with-reduce/179822#179822).

In the following situation, I find that given my assumptions, it is indeed possible for $g$ to be negative.

```
g = f - (-1 + f) P + (-2 f + 2 f P) w
Assuming[0 <= w <= 1 && 0 <= P <= 1 && 0 <= f <= 1 , FullSimplify@Reduce[g < 0]]
P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) < 0
```

Given this finding, can Mathematica output combinations of regions of P, f, and w, that give the specified result $P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) < 0$ ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
FullSimplify @ Reduce[{P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) < 0, 
   0 <= w <= 1 && 0 <= P <= 1 && 0 <= f <= 1}, { P, f, w}]
```

> ```
> 0 <= P < 1/2 &&  
> -(P/(-1 + P)) < f <= 1 &&   
> (f + P - f P)/(2 f - 2 f P) < w <= 1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
 P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) < 0
 , {P, f, w}
 ]

RegionPlot3D[
 P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w) < 0
 , {P, -3, 3}
 , {f, -3, 3}
 , {w, -3, 3}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]